# SHA256 in C# not matching on two objects with same structure and data. Could it be due to different architectures?

Tags: c#, json, hash, cryptography, sha256

I have an application where I store data records in Mongo on an IoT device and in the cloud. To build the records I stuff a typical dotnet object and then serialize it to JSON and hash it for integrity checking. Then I push the record with the hash to the cloud.

The issue I am having is that when I try to check the hash from the record in the cloud, I cannot get them to match even though I am doing doing the exact same process as when I run it on the IoT device. The IoT device is a Debian based device so my dotnet application is running in a Docker container on the device.

Could the issue be that the SHA256 algorithm in System.Security.Cryptography creates a different result on different architectures?

Here is how I create the hash on the device;

```
        try { LocalRecord.meter_id = strMeterID; } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.meter_time_UTC = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(); } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.meter_time_UTC_ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks; } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.gps_lat = strLatDec; } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.gps_lon = strLonDec; } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.kwh_tot = eKMv3_RequestB.kWh_Tot; } catch (Exception) { }

        try 
        {
            //need to serialize the DTO to a JSON string, then hash the JSON string, put the hash into
            //the DTO then serialize again. This is not ideal but works for now
            string convertedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LocalRecord, Formatting.Indented);
            string hash = HashJSON(convertedJson);
```

And here is how it is created in my checker app;

```
try { LocalRecord.meter_id = doc.GetValue("meter_id").ToString(); } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.meter_time_UTC = doc.GetValue("meter_time_UTC").ToString(); } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.meter_time_UTC_ticks = doc.GetValue("meter_time_UTC_ticks").ToInt64(); } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.gps_lat = doc.GetValue("gps_lat").ToString(); } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.gps_lon = doc.GetValue("gps_lon").ToString(); } catch (Exception) { }
        try { LocalRecord.kwh_tot = doc.GetValue("kwh_tot").ToString(); } catch (Exception) { }

        try
        {
            //need to serialize the DTO to a JSON string, then hash the JSON string, put the hash into
            //the DTO then serialize again. This is not ideal but works for now
            string convertedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LocalRecord, Formatting.Indented);
            string hash = HashJSON(convertedJson);
```

The hash function is exactly the same in both applications;

```
// Create a SHA256   
            using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
            {
                // ComputeHash - returns byte array  
                byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonstring));

                // Convert byte array to a string formatted as lowercase hex
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
                }
                return builder.ToString();
            }
```

And the data in both the local record and the cloud record appears exactly the same as is my LocalRecord class as I copied and pasted it from one project to the other but I cannot for the life of me to get the hashes to align. I have tried with multiple records.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are you sure the json formatting uses the same end of line characters? linux `LF` vs windows `CR LF`

Comment: Side note: I don't see any code that *tries* to produce consistent (normalized) JSON. I'd expect every ToString call to have precise format specified for example. The code in the question is written to behave differently depending on where it runs/how the data is computed - you may want to show actual (and not simplified) version.

Comment: Did you eyeball the two versions of `convertedJson` to see if they are in fact identical?

Comment: The culprit is most likely `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()`. The format it uses is based on the thread culture, which is usually the system culture. The resulting string can and often will vary between systems.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I tried removing CR from all the strings. This did not result in any change to the calculate SHA256.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee the DateTime strings are the same. For the Hash Checker application I am taking the values from the database and repacking the exact same class with the values and rerunning the hash check.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am not sure what you mean about the actual versions vs simplified. This is the actual code I am running in both applications.

I will try the ToString formatting as you suggest but as I am taking the string from the first application and putting them into the second information straight out of my Mongo Records I think they should be exactly the same though I admit, in binary form they may be different due to different cultures on the different architectures.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I will try that today. It's a bit tedious to troubleshoot on the device side application as I cannot directly debug so must rely on log files or console.writelines

Comment: @500-InternalServerError you hit the nail on the head. Getting at the raw JSON from each end found the issue and of course it was programmer error no mystical architecture issue.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: It was a simple program issue, no mystical architecture effects. I was not clearing the LocalRecord so when hashing I was also hashing the hash from the last record, like a miniature internal blockchain.

All sorted now and apologies to all whose time I wasted and thanks to 500-InternalServerError who pushed me to do what I should have earlier.

Cheers,
ODT